# Can i pull data directly from html with WTForms/Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Is there a way to pull data directly from html tag with WTForms

on WTForms documentation you have to put

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
    <form method=post>
      <dl>
        {{ render_field(form.username) }}
        {{ render_field(form.email) }}
        {{ render_field(form.password) }}
        {{ render_field(form.confirm) }}
        {{ render_field(form.accept_tos) }}
      </dl>
      <p><input type=submit value=Register>
    </form>
```

on the registration page (which i am trying to avoid)

on main `__init__.py`

```
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, StringField, PasswordField, validators

class RegistrationForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email Address', [validators.Length(min=6, max=35)])
    password = PasswordField('New Password', [
        validators.DataRequired(),
        validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords must match')
    ])
    confirm = PasswordField('Repeat Password')
    accept_tos = BooleanField('I accept the TOS', [validators.DataRequired()])
```

what i tried so far but didn't work

```
    name = TextField(request.form['username'], [validators.Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = TextField(request.form['email'], [validators.Length(min=6, max=35)])
    password = PasswordField(request.form['password1'], [
        validators.DataRequired(),
        validators.EqualTo('confirmpw', message='Passwords must match')
    ])
    confirmpw = PasswordField(request.form['password2'])
    accept_tos = BooleanField('I accept the TOS', [validators.DataRequired()])
```

my html

```
  <form  method=post>
    <dl>
      <dt>Name:
      <dd><input type=text name=username >
      <dt>email:
      <dd><input type=email name=email> 
      <dt>Password:
      <dd><input type=password name=password1 >
      <dt>confrim Password:
      <dd><input type=password name=password2 >
    </dl>
    <p><input  type=submit value="register" >
  </form>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Form rendering is flexible and robust, while doing it yourself like that is brittle, a nightmare to maintain (you must manually keep everything in sync) and adds nothing.

Comment: i have the register form in multiple places so i want to pull data from name tag on html to make it easier than writing render_fields on many places